# Simple, editable design system for clients?

Tags: software-recommendation, user-experience, template-design, website-templates

I am creating a design system for a client with a focus on their marketing materials. They want to be able to make small changes and export files on their own eg. everyone month their web banner may have updated text. Something like Canva templates.

I know that this could be done easily on a platform like Figma, but is there a user-friendly platform for non-designers where this information could be organised?

Comment: The problem with user friendly is that different users have different friendlyness factors. So this means thatuser friendly either means too simple to be useful or does not exist.

Comment: Perfect chance to up sell services... "for a nominal fee I'll handle changes you want.... up to X per month for only $xxx" -- remember it's NOT just making small edits... it's maintaining overall design continuity, branding, technical aspects, exporting properly.... you have more knowledge than you seem to be giving yourself credit for. To *clients* "small edits" seem harmless... but sure enough.. even the best intentioned client will do something to devalue the marketing... "Oooo Zapf Chancery is a cool font.... how about that with Brush Script and Comic Sans! ooo and add a big drop shadow!"

Comment: @Scott Haha not the Comic Sans!

Answer (score 3):

> Something like Canva templates

What if you consider... Canva?

You can upload files, that can be the base file, probably the background, and then someone just log in and edit the file? It also has something like Canva for teams, which I have not used, but there it is for a reason.

> every month their web banner may have updated text

Some other options can be: files on a shared drive or dropbox, google docs using a presentation, a web-based system that takes the text from a text file and renders an html5 banner, etc.

Software is a relative thing. Again, use Canva, or google docs, or PowerPoint, or maybe Gimp, or someone should learn how to use Indesign and InCopy, or download a PHP script to read txt files, use a FTP client, or pull data from a web form and database...

---

You could implement a ton of things... but every system needs capacitation and time to implement it.

> with a focus on their marketing materials

But if the company really wants "marketing materials" aka "Effective marketing materials" they should have a "marketing person". If the company is small, they probably should hire a freelancer, which is probably you.

If the marketing material is reusing the same again and again, only changing text, probably it is not important at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had a client once ask me to do this for a digital menu. Because of my relationship with the client, it made sense for me to give them a file that they could edit instead of me doing small edits over time. I wasn't getting paid for the revisions.

I asked the client what programs they were familiar with working in and they said PowerPoint. So I made the design in Illustrator and turned that into a PowerPoint working file.

If the client only has to make basic text changes, then I think this solution is OK. I would say a decent amount of people have basic experience using Word and PowerPoint.

Comment: This sounds more like an editable *design*, not a *design system*.  I think the OP is asking for some software that allows variables to be changed. Doing so then automatically modifies a bunch of designs.